# Space between divs seem to change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a space between the black keys:

[image]

I've tried `margin-left`, but it still stay the same. My css is dynamically generated using javascript:

```
        //Append inside a pre-made window
        this.keyboardDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var attr = document.createAttribute("id");
        attr.value = "mkbKeyboardDiv";
        this.keyboardDiv.setAttributeNode(attr);
        widgetWindow.getWidgetBody().append(this.keyboardDiv);

        .......

        var mkbKeyboardDiv = this.keyboardDiv;
        mkbKeyboardDiv.style.display = 'inline';
        mkbKeyboardDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
        mkbKeyboardDiv.style.border = '0px';
        mkbKeyboardDiv.style.width = '300px';
        mkbKeyboardDiv.style.top = '0px';
        mkbKeyboardDiv.innerHTML = '';

        mkbKeyboardDiv.innerHTML = ' <div id="keyboardHolder2"><table class="white"><tbody><tr id="myrow"></tr></tbody></table><table class="black"><tbody><tr id="myrow2"></tr></tbody></table></div>'

        var keyboardHolder2 = docById('keyboardHolder2');
        keyboardHolder2.style.bottom = '10px';
        keyboardHolder2.style.left = '0px';
        keyboardHolder2.style.height = '145px'
        keyboardHolder2.style.width = '700px';
        keyboardHolder2.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

        var blackRow = document.getElementsByClassName('black');
        blackRow[0].style.top = '1px';

        ........

        var parenttbl2 = document.getElementById('myrow2');
        var newel2 = document.createElement('td');
        var elementid2 = document.getElementsByTagName('td').length;
        newel2.setAttribute('id', 'blackRow' + myrow2Id.toString());
        newel2.style.textAlign = 'center';
        if ([2,6,9,13,16,20].indexOf(myrow2Id) !== -1) {
            parenttbl2.appendChild(newel2);
            var el = docById('blackRow' + myrow2Id.toString());
            el.style.background = 'transparent';
            el.style.border = 'none';
            el.style.zIndex = '10';
            el.style.position = 'relative';
            p--;
            myrow2Id++;
            continue;
         }

         this.layout[p].objId = 'blackRow' + myrow2Id.toString();
         myrow2Id++;
         newel2.style.position = 'relative';
         newel2.style.zIndex = '200';
         parenttbl2.appendChild(newel2);
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floatingWindows"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#mkbKeyboardDiv {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border: 0 !important;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85) !important;
  width: 1020px;
}
```

I think I'm missing something, I just can't think of it. Is there any other way of putting space on each of the black div tags?

EDIT: I've added the HTML and CSS. The CSS is only for the keyboard's container. The white keys and black keys' CSS are all generated using Javascript

Comment: please can you show your html and css too - see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: I don't really understand why this is generated dynamically. And why you would use tables, which are difficult to style. Have you tried using CSS grid, which will probably simplify this code?

Comment: We need a **functional** demo. The fact that the elements are generated by JS does mean that you can't provide thir HTML & CSS